# Confusion on $\vert\vert \varphi\vert\vert_{p}$ where $p \in [1,\infty[$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, smooth-functions

Let $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ and for $\epsilon > 0$ define  $\varphi_{\epsilon}(x):=\epsilon^{-n}\varphi(x/\epsilon)$ such that  $\varphi_{\epsilon} \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ with compact support.

Determine $\vert \vert \varphi_{\epsilon}\vert \vert_{p}$ with $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ in dependence on $\epsilon$

I understand the case $p =\infty$, namely $\vert \vert \varphi_{\epsilon}\vert \vert_{\infty}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb R^{n}}|\varphi_{\epsilon}(x)|=\sup_{x \in \mathbb R^{n}}|\epsilon^{-n}\varphi(x/\epsilon)|=\epsilon^{-n}\sup_{ x\in \mathbb R^{n}}|\varphi(x/\epsilon)|=\epsilon^{-n}||\varphi||_{\infty}$

I get confused by the case $p \in [1, \infty[$

Surely, by definition:

$\vert \vert \varphi_{\epsilon}\vert \vert_{p}^{p}=\int_{\mathbb R^{n}}|\epsilon^{-n}\varphi(x/\epsilon)|^{p}dx$ and then by substitution $( x/\epsilon = x^{'}\Rightarrow dx/\epsilon^{n}=dx^{'})(*)$

**First question**: surely differentiating $n-$times has no effect on $\epsilon$, so surely $(*)$ should be $dx/\epsilon=dx^{'}$ rather than $dx/\epsilon^{n}=dx^{'}$

In any case, assuming $(*)$ holds: $\int_{\mathbb R^{n}}\epsilon^{-np}|\varphi(x^{'})|^{p}\epsilon^{n}dx^{'}=\epsilon^{-n(p-1)}\int_{\mathbb R^{n}}|\varphi(x^{'})|^{p}dx^{'}\Rightarrow \vert \vert \varphi_{\epsilon}\vert \vert_{p}=\epsilon^{\frac{-n(p-1)}{p}}||\varphi||_{p}$

**Second Question:** I have been told that the answer must be $\vert \vert \varphi_{\epsilon}\vert \vert_{p}=\vert \vert \varphi\vert \vert_{p}$

But I cannot see what I did wrong.

Comment: Your answer seems fine to me! Maybe I'm missing something too xd. With regards to your first point, you're not differentiating n times but are differentiating n variables each with an $\varepsilon$ scaling. This is what gives you the $\varepsilon^n$!

Comment: Indeed the $L^p$ norm will in general be different between the two. The situation is obvious for $L^\infty$ (you haven't changed the extrema of $\varphi$), and it is slightly less obvious that it is the same for $L^1$ (essentially you've concentrated the "mass" of $\varphi$ more tightly but also stretched it by exactly the right amount to compensate for the change in "volume"). But for $L^p$ the requisite rescaling is different.

Comment: As for this issue about the change of variable, this is part of why people sometimes use explicit notations like $\vec{x}$ or $\mathbf{x}$ to denote vectors. Here it is true that say $dx_1/\epsilon=dx_1'$ but there is one such $\epsilon$ for every component of $x$.